# AR.JS Can't get Video or Picture working with NFT only 3D

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I finally have given up as I can't get AR.JS to run with a simple NFT marker that should display a Video or a PNG image over it. If I run it with a GLTF Model it works without problems. I tried changing the scale and position to see if it is somehow behind the marker etc. but that doesn't help in any way.

The console doesn't throw me any errors as well.

Could anybody throw me a short fix as I tried a lot of different stuff but nothing gets displayed.

Link to page with marker https://natrium83.github.io

Link to 3D example https://natrium83.github.io/ar3d/

Link to Picture example https://natrium83.github.io/arbild/

Link to Video example https://natrium83.github.io/arvideo/

Here is the code for the image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Image based tracking AR.js demo</title>
    <!-- import aframe and then ar.js with image tracking / location based features -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

    <!-- style for the loader -->
    <style>
      .arjs-loader {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        z-index: 9999;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .arjs-loader div {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded. Loading may take a while according to the device computational power -->
    <div class="arjs-loader">
      <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
    </div>

    <!-- a-frame scene -->
    <a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
      renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
      embedded
      arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;">
      <!-- a-nft is the anchor that defines an Image Tracking entity -->
      <!-- on 'url' use the path to the Image Descriptors created before. -->
      <!-- the path should end with the name without the extension e.g. if file is trex.fset' the path should end with trex -->
      <a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="https://natrium83.github.io/ar3d/assets/marker_image"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5">
          <!-- as a child of the a-nft entity, you can define the content to show. here's a GLTF model entity -->
          <a-entity>



          <a-image src="https://natrium83.github.io/arbild/assets/bild.png"
              scale="5 5 5"
              position="100 100 0"
              crossorigin
          ></a-image>
          </a-entity>

      </a-nft>
      <!-- static camera that moves according to the device movemenents -->
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: Make sure the image is not facing back the camera because it won't be rendered. Position the image in a regular 3D scene to make sure everything works and then try to rotate when placed within `a-nft`

Comment: hey :) what happened? Did it work? You have a working link? thx

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the size of the media. Despite the documentation saying '1' = 1 meter, I had to set the size to height='160' width='120' to get mine working. Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this thread! I have kinda the same problem with image tracking. But I have tried with the marker-based something as follow to play video beside a marker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>#</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.1.2/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('vidhandler', {
            init: function() {
                this.toggle = false;
                this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");
                this.vid.pause();
            },
            tick: function() {
                if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
                    if (!this.toggle) {
                        this.toggle = true;
                        this.vid.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.toggle = false;
                    this.vid.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        function refrespage() {
            location.reload();
        }

        function playvid() {
            vid.play();
        }
    </script>
  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene embedded artoolkit='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; maxDetectionRate: 60; canvasWidth: 200; canvasHeight: 200'>
      <a-assets>
        <video preload="auto" id="vid" autoplay loop="true" src="foo.mp4" crossorigin webkit-playsinline playsinline controls>
          <source src="foo.mp4">
        </video>
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker id="memarker" 
                type="pattern" 
                preset="hiro" 
                smooth="true" 
                smoothCount="10" 
                smoothTolerance="0.01" 
                smoothThreshold="5" vidhandler>
        <a-plane scale = '10 10 0' position='-4.5 0.1 -5.5' rotation="-90 0 0" material='transparent:true;src:#vid' controls></a-plane>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still working on image-tracking though. I'd post an update if I got something.

**Side note: this might not work on ios devices**

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28309017)